# How to get rid of this error from datetime module and run codes efficiently

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, smtp, smtplib

I was writing a code to send out birthday wishes. After importing all the necessary modules, I keep getting error after running codes using Pycharm. Here's the code

```
import _datetime as dt
import pandas
import random
import smtplib

MY_EMAIL = "email@gmail.com"
MY_PASSWORD = "*********"

# Checking if today matches a birthday in the csv file
month = dt.datetime.now().month
day = dt.datetime.now().day
today = (month, day)

# Using pandas to read the csv file
data = pandas.read_csv("birthdays.csv")

# Dictionary comprehension template for pandas Dataframe look like this
birthdays_dict = {(data_row["Month"], data_row["Day"]): data_row for (index, data_row) in data.iterrows()}

#Comparing to see if today's month/day tuple matches one of the keys in birthday
if today in birthdays_dict:
    birthday_person = birthdays_dict[today]
    file_path = f"./letter_templates/letter_{random.randint(1, 3)}.txt"
    with open(file_path) as letter_file:
        content = letter_file.read()
        content = content.replace("[NAME]", birthday_person["Name"])

    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(user=MY_EMAIL, password=MY_PASSWORD)
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=MY_EMAIL,
            to_addrs=birthday_person["Email"],
            msg=f"Subject:Happy Birthday!\n\n{content}"
        )
```

The error I get was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/faqee/PycharmProjects/100DaysOfCode/Day 32/send_birthday_wishes.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "C:\Users\faqee\PycharmProjects\100DaysOfCode\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\faqee\PycharmProjects\100DaysOfCode\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\faqee\PycharmProjects\100DaysOfCode\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\faqee\PycharmProjects\100DaysOfCode\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\faqee\PycharmProjects\100DaysOfCode\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'datetime_CAPI'
2021-09-17 04:41:33.071350
2021
9
4
1998-04-10 05:00:00

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've checked google and also read the documentation but couldn't get a possible solution to solve this.

PS: I have set my mail to allow python access it and send mail from the security mode

Comment: try uninstall and re-install pandas/numpy. Looks like the error occurred when trying to import pandas itself

Comment: It seems that your pandas/numpy and your python are not compatible (maybe different version, or different settings). Sometimes is just caused by leftover files during updates (maybe they were in use, but so when executing, python mixes versions)